# Scatter plot with ggplot2 colored by dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to do a scatter plot with colored by dates.  Currently I am doing the following but I have not been able to find a way to get the dates in a good readable format for the legend even though the graph looks the way I want it.  I tried formatting them as 20140101 for example but the whole year falls within a small range i.e < 20141231 and I don't get different colors within the year.

```
data(cars)
cars['dt'] = seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()-980,-20)

ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist,colour = as.integer(dt))) + geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c('red','green','blue'))
```

Can someone recommend a solution please?  To be specific I would like every date to be a different color/shade of a color.  (For my actual data I have about 5-6 years of daily data)

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add a labeler function:

```
ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist,colour=as.integer(dt))) + geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c('red','green','blue'), labels=as.Date)
```

[image]

Comment: I get the following error:    Error in as.Date.numeric(breaks) : 'origin' must be supplied

Answer (score 11):

Getting around the 'origin must be supplied error'...
One approach is to make a wrapper for as.Date that has the origin specified, than call this as a labeller.

```
as.Date_origin <- function(x){
  as.Date(x, origin = '1970-01-01')
}

data(cars)
cars['dt'] = seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()-980,-20)

ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist,colour=as.integer(dt))) + geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = 'Date', colours=c('red','green','blue'), labels=as.Date_origin)
```

Comment: @Tonys Ladson your workaround is very helpful. I have a follow-up question. How do you format the label of the legend to "%d %Y"? I don't know where to do the 'format = ' in any of the arguments. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @mand3rd. You can do this. In the `as.Date_origin` function change  `as.Date(x, origin = '1970-01-01')` to
  `format(as.Date(x, origin = '1970-01-01'), format = '%d %Y')`

Comment: This also works as an anonymous function:

`scale_colour_gradientn(name = 'Date', colours=c('red','green','blue'), labels=function(x) { as.Date(x, origin = '1970-01-01') })`

Answer (score 0):

`scale_colour_gradient` is mainly used for continuous data, so we should first transform date data to a continuous format using `as.integer()`. Otherwise, it might raise an error, like "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".

In many cases, the date column is factor, we need do `as.integer(as.Date())` to get the right transformed data. Not a big problem, but sometimes might be tricky. The `origin` in the self-defined function is `1970-01-01`, which is a system attribute. Read
[as.Date](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/as.Date) for more information.

```
data(cars)
cars['dt'] = seq(Sys.Date(),Sys.Date()-980,-20)

trans_date <- function(x){
  as.Date(x, origin = '1970-01-01')
}
    
p <- ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist,colour=as.integer(as.Date(dt)))) 
p + geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
    scale_colour_gradientn(name = 'Date', colours=c('red','green','blue'), labels=trans_date)
```

Comment: It isn't obvious that this answer is different from another already posted answer.

Comment: Hi @ouflak. This is not an answer that totally different others. You did not see the value of the differences as you might have had a deep understanding in R and other answers. But I did spend some time to figure out why we can use scale_colour_gradientn to do so and fix the data format to adapt to my case, even if they are just some little tricks. As such, I do not want others to waste a time to fix the same issue and therefore wrote what I have learned to the answer, hoping to help those are also fresh. But I also appreciate that you took a time to look at the answer and made a comment.

Comment: @ouflak Maybe next time I can make comments to other answers to address my points, although they might not occur in one answer. Thanks!