# Format date in legend for ggplot in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, format, legend

This [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311489/scatter-plot-with-ggplot2-colored-by-dates) posted 3 years ago is very similar to mine and was lucky enough that it did solve my problem. However, I have a follow-up question regarding the format of the legend's label. I would like to make it into `MMYYYY`. I know I can do a `format = "%b %Y"` but I am not sure which argument to place it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you try: `scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")` ? If it is not working, please provide a reproducible example of your dataset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @dc37 Thanks for your reply.  Date is not an element of the x-axis. The link provided has the reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

Posting the answer with reference to the other question.

```
ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist,colour=as.integer(dt))) + geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c('red','green','blue'), labels=as.Date)
```

this was an answer in the other question and if you want to format the date as MMYYYY then,

```
   Date_F <- function(x){
      format(as.Date(x, origin = '1970-01-01',"%Y-%m-%d"),"%m%Y")
    }

    ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist,colour=as.integer(dt))) + geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
      scale_colour_gradientn(name = 'Date', colours=c('red','green','blue'),labels=Date_F)
```

Hope this helps!